# What is a good way to implement passing value around pages

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

So I have this edit button from ../Edit/ that goes into ../CodeNamePage/Index?filterId=123 by passing the id value = 123 from the edit page. In CodeNamePage I have a create new link that will allow user to create a new entry.

I would like to pass in the value of that 123 from ../CodeNamePage/Index?filterId=123 into the create page like ../CodeNamePage/Create?id=123 and auto fill in the id text box field with 123. Would like some suggestions or recommendations on this.

Answer (score 0):

One method I can think of is to upload your data on a MySQL database, and then get the data in the create page from your database, it should be something like this:

your index:

```
    <?php
   $link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name' ); // connect to the database

   if ( $_GET ) {

  $data = $_GET['yourdata'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO tableName (data) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $data)."')";

  mysqli_query( $link, $query );

}

?>
```

Your create page:

PHP:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'username', 'password', 'db_name' );

$query = "SELECT data FROM tableName"; // You'd want to do a more specific query here, for example by querying the data that has a specific username or ID or whatever user-identification method you use, this will currently grab data from ALL entries in the table.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

$data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

HTML:

```
  <p><?php 

        echo $data['data'];

        ?></p>
```

I gave you an example with a p tag but you can use the code on any element.

Comment: I am not using php so are those convertible to asp.net mvc html ?

Comment: Oh, the MySQL queries should work with any language since you are using SQL language here, however you'll have to find the equivalent for some PHP commands like  mysqli_query and some stuff, nonetheless, the idea is still the same index > database > create page..